# Monitor changes in a record spanning multiple related tables

Tags: sql

I seek the help of the advance SQL gurus in here.

I have 5 Related tables: table A + B + C + D + E in which table A exists in B,C,D,E as a foreign key.

I further have one big table that combines all rows from all the 5 table, namely:
'table A + B + C + D + E'.

I'm looking for a way to monitor changes from either one of the 5 tables and insert the entire related record (A + B + C + D + E), be they UPDATES or INSERTS into the big table: 'table A + B + C + D + E'.

[image]

I'm still at level novice with my SQL programming.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try trigers. Not so elegant but it will work

Answer (score 0):

OK, nobody's touched it in more than a day, and it is related to some exploration I've been doing into the interaction between triggers and transactions, so I'll tweak one of my experiments to (hopefully) make it apply to your problem.

But first, I'm not clear on exactly what you're doing so I'm going to make a few assumptions. I'll state them for clarity.

1) I assume you've considered using a view for the Big Table and rejected that for some reason. If you haven't, stop now and look into that, it's often the best solution for cases like this. You can even make a view based on multiple tables update-able by writing an INSTEAD OF trigger for it. It will always have the latest data without any timing issues or logic problems.

2) I assume you want changes APPENDED to your big table, as you said, though the change to UPDATE shouldn't be hard. Just bear in mind my solution is for APPEND.

3) I assume you don't care about deletes, since you specifically mention UPDATES and INSERTS

4) I assume that when you say foreign key relationship you mean a real formal one, and that it's a one to one relationship.

5) I assume you need the Big Table updated in real time, you could probably get a more robust solution if you just flagged dirty rows and did an hourly or nightly update based on that.

Trying to explain the solution is hard, so I'll give you a template that you can expand with your specific schema. The basic premise is to attach "after" triggers to the update and insert events for your component tables. Each trigger tries to combine its changed rows with the matching rows in A and write the whole thing to the big table (ABC). I only used 3 tables, you can easily extend to 5.

Note that because you have a foreign key relationship and the triggers are "after", you are assured that the A row exists  or the FK constraint would have rolled back the transaction and not fired the trigger. So A is inner joined to a changed table, but the others are left outer joined.

First, create the base tables you'll be working with

```
USE [JUNK]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
--DROP TABLE A
--DROP TABLE B
--DROP TABLE C
--DROP TABLE ABC
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [AID] [int] NOT NULL, --primary key, not enforced here to facilitate sample data entry
    [ADat] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [BID] [int] NOT NULL, --primary key
    [AID] [int] NOT NULL, --foreign key on A, not enforced here to facilitate sample data entry
    [BDat] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[C](
    [CID] [int] NOT NULL, --primary key
    [AID] [int] NOT NULL, --foreign key on A, not enforced here to facilitate sample data entry
    [CDat] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ABC](
    [abcID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AID] [int] NOT NULL, --foreign key on A, not enforced here to facilitate sample data entry
    [ADat] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BDat] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CDat] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ABC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [abcID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Next, set up the triggers that will monitor the component tables and update the big table when one is changed

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author: Robert Sheahan
-- Create date: 2014-07-24
-- Description: Testing multiple trigger interaction in transactions,
--              logs changes to a distributed record to a big table.
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trA_IU 
   ON  dbo.A 
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO ABC (AID, ADat, BDat, CDat)
    SELECT A.AID, ADat, BDat, CDat
    FROM A 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.AID = B.AID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN C on A.AID = C.AID 
END
GO

-- DROP TRIGGER dbo.trB_IU
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trB_IU 
   ON  dbo.B 
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO ABC (AID, ADat, BDat, CDat)
    SELECT A.AID, ADat, BDat, CDat
    FROM A
        INNER JOIN B on A.AID = B.AID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN C on A.AID = C.AID 
END
GO

-- DROP TRIGGER dbo.trC_IU; GO;
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trC_IU 
   ON  dbo.C 
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO ABC (AID, ADat, BDat, CDat)
    SELECT A.AID, ADat, BDat, CDat
    FROM A 
        INNER JOIN C on A.AID = C.AID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.AID = B.AID 
END
GO
```

Finally, test it and refine it to meet your specific needs.

```
INSERT INTO A (AID, ADat) VALUES (1,'Hello'),(2,'Goodbye')
INSERT INTO B (BID, AID, BDat) VALUES (11,1,'new'),(12,2,'cruel')
INSERT INTO C (CID, AID, CDat) VALUES (21,1,'world!'),(22,2,'world')
UPDATE B SET BDat = 'old'    WHERE AID=1
UPDATE C SET CDat = 'planet' WHERE AID=1
SELECT * FROM ABC
```